# How to Remove duplicate values from Multidimentional array with single unique value in all array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-unique

I have multi-dimentional array like below,

```
$product = array( 
            "2e471a22b1b994a7cb3f3a40cee9fba2" => array (
               "product" => 6004,
               "unique_key" => 3a8a5cb029ee3b92cfc90de23e2329ab,    
               "product_id" => 51,
        "line_total"=>99,
         "quantity"=>1,
        "data"=> array(
        "id"=> 51,
        "post"=>array(
            "ID"=>51,
            "post_title"=>"Prodcut four - control",            
            ),
        "price"=>99    
        )
            ),
    "a7d0f813832ec8a2bf24269ff7145d0c" => array (
               "product" => 6004,
               "unique_key" => c30d1ca26d30aa3dc3c9aa04f0b585ce,    
               "product_id" => 51,
        "line_total"=>99,
        "quantity"=>1,
        "data"=> array(
        "id"=> 51,
        "post"=>array(
            "ID"=>51,
            "post_title"=>"Prodcut four - control",            
            ),
        "price"=>99    
        )
            )
         );
```

Need to remove the duplicate values based on 'product_id' array value and increase the quantity values based on number of products. 
Note: The above array have 'unique key' too so any single unique key is needed in array result.

```
Expected Result should be:
$resultproduct = array( 
        "2e471a22b1b994a7cb3f3a40cee9fba2" => array (
           "product" => 6004,
           "unique_key" => 3a8a5cb029ee3b92cfc90de23e2329ab,    
           "product_id" => 51,
    "line_total"=>99,
     "quantity"=>2,
    "data"=> array(
    "id"=> 51,
    "post"=>array(
        "ID"=>51,
        "post_title"=>"Prodcut four - control",            
        ),
    "price"=>99    
    )
        ));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: Loop product array in foreach then Built the array structure the way you like and increment counter if you find same product id

Comment: Hey Ramkumar, where is the data coming from?

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND Need to remove the duplicates value too, all the Products have unique key, so array_unique doesn't works.

Comment: @SyedMohamedAladeen In above array all the products have unique keys so array_unique not works. The link you given have all the values in a array index are same but it doesn't works in my array as all array index have different unique key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working code at eval.in](https://eval.in/548611)

I try and make the code easy to understand so more variables and lines of code than is absolutely required.

Explanation:

1) Need to use the one of original `product` array index as the output table key e.g. "2e471a22b1b994a7cb3f3a40cee9fba2" for product 51.

2) It needs to be fast relating input productId to the output key. So, I used a lookup table `ProductIdList` that matches `productId` to `output` key.

It is then a two stage lookup to find the entry in the output and add quantities to it.

The code:

```
// create a product_id => first key table
$productIdList = array();

// output...
$productTotal = array();

foreach ($product as $origIndex => $entry) {

    $curProductId = $entry['product_id'];

    // check product_id exists in the lookup...
    if (isset($productIdList[$curProductId])) { // add to the total...

        $productTotalIndex = $productIdList[$curProductId];

        $productTotal[$productTotalIndex]['quantity'] +=  $entry['quantity'];
    }
    else { // add the entry to the output and the productIdList...

        $productIdList[$curProductId] = $origIndex;

        $productTotal[$origIndex] = $entry;
    }
}
```

Output: The totals array:

```
Array
(
    [2e471a22b1b994a7cb3f3a40cee9fba2] => Array
        (
            [product] => 6004
            [unique_key] => 3a8a5cb029ee3b92cfc90de23e2329ab
            [product_id] => 51
            [line_total] => 99
            [quantity] => 2
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 51
                    [post] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 51
                            [post_title] => Prodcut four - control
                        )
                    [price] => 99
                )
        )

    [test02] => Array
        (
            [product] => 6664
            [unique_key] => c30d1ca26d30aa3dc3c9aa04f0b585ce
            [product_id] => 666
            [line_total] => 99
            [quantity] => 579
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 666
                    [post] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 666
                            [post_title] => Prodcut 666 - control
                        )
                    [price] => 99
                )
        )
)
```

The productId to original key list:

```
array (size=2)
  51 => string '2e471a22b1b994a7cb3f3a40cee9fba2' (length=32)
  666 => string 'test02' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over each product and use the product_id as the key for a new array. This adds the quantities as it goes, so should work for any quantities other than 1.

```
$result = [];

foreach ($product as $p)
{
    if (isset($result[$p['product_id']]))
    {
        $result[$p['product_id']]['quantity']+= $p['quantity'];
    }

    else
    {
        $result[$p['product_id']] = $p;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```